# Tell PyCharm to put Copyright notice at top of file (line 1, or after #!)?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have configured PyCharm to add a [Copyright notice](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/copyright-profiles.html) to all project files. However, it seems to prefer adding them after any `!#` line or module docstring, when present. During a [pull-request review](https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps-online/pull/1#issuecomment-450753306), I have been asked to put the Copyright notice at the top of the file, i.e. line 1.

Is it possible to have PyCharm put the Copyright notice **above the module docstring**, as close to line 1 as possible?

Comment: Tell whoever reviewed your pull request that if the `#!` isn't the first line, it won't work.

Comment: Yes, my question mainly pertains to the module docstring. I.e. how can I tell Pycharm to place the Copyright notice above the module docstring?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting for placing it above or below other comments. I think the default is "Before other comments".

The setting is located in Editor -> Copyright -> Formatting -> Python. The particular setting is "Relative Location", and you will want to set it to "Before other comments"